# SQLite Android: Custom database directory creation; File contains a path seperator

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Is it possible in SQLite to place the database files on a seperate folder inside of yourpackagename instead of yourpackagename/databases?

For example, I pass this string to the constructor of my SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
    data/data/com.example.app/appbooks/App Book 1.db
```

Also tried doing this as the string, same result:

```
    dbName = "data" + File.separator + "data" + File.separator + "com.example.app" + File.separator + "appbooks" + File.separator + dbName + ".db";
```

After that, I receive the an error in logcat at execution that the string above contains a path separator. I tried doing the usual slashes and replacing those slashes with File.separator, but the error still persists.

```
    05-06 21:23:25.896: E/AndroidRuntime(5214): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File data/data/com.example.app/appbooks/App Book 1.db contains a path separator
```

Comment: Is there a reason for creating the database in another location? I can't imagine the use case for this. Also, you should not use hardcoded paths - use `Context.getDatabasePath()` instead.

Comment: Yes, there is. I know it isn't a good practice, but I just need to know if I could actually place it in another folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your databases *must* be in the directory returned by `getDatabasePath()`.

If you really want to have an hierarchy of database file names, replace the path separator with any other character. (In Linux, file names can contain *any* character except `/`.)
If you want to be particularly evil, use a backslash:

```java
final String myFakeSeparator = "\\";
...
dbName = ... + File.separator + "appbooks" + myFakeSeparator + dbName + ".db";
```